# TruncDate timezone parameter is not working in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

Not able to change TImezone  in Trunc functions. It always take timezone from settings.py

```
import pytz
ind = pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
```

Query:

```
queryset = Order.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at', tzinfo=ind)).values('date')
```

While inspecting sql query by `queryset.query`

```
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`nm_order`.`created_at`, 'UTC', UTC)) AS `date` FROM `nm_order`
```

Reference: [Trunc in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc)



But for [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#extract), it's get working

ORM:

```
queryset = Order.objects.annotate(date=ExtractDay('created_at',tzinfo=ind)).values('date')
```

Query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM CONVERT_TZ(`nm_order`.`created_at`, 'UTC', Asia/Calcutta)) AS `date` FROM `nm_order`
```

Am I miss something in `Trunc` ?

TimeZone Settings in my `settings.py`

```
IME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`TruncDay()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.datetime.TruncDay) instead of `TruncDate`. In the usage example just below that section of the documentation you'll see the difference between the two.

`TruncDate` does not take a timezone option - it uses the current timezone and gives you the date in that timezone.

I think the distinction between the two is that `TruncDate` returns a `DateField` which by definition cannot be timezone-aware. `TruncDay` on the other hand returns a `DateTimeField`(with time portion set to 00:00:00), which can be timezone aware.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: TruncDate now has an optional tzinfo parameter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate

Answer (score 4):

From django 3.2, TruncDate now accepts tzinfo parameter. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate

Answer (score 0):

After Inspecting TruncDate Class looks like it doesn't have timezone option

```
class TruncDate(TruncBase):
    kind = 'date'
    lookup_name = 'date'

    @cached_property
    def output_field(self):
        return DateField()

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        # Cast to date rather than truncate to date.
        lhs, lhs_params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        tzname = timezone.get_current_timezone_name() if settings.USE_TZ else None
        sql, tz_params = connection.ops.datetime_cast_date_sql(lhs, tzname)
        lhs_params.extend(tz_params)
        return sql, lhs_params
```